# Deploy DocPad to Gandi.net Simple Hosting

Tags: node.js, vhosts, docpad

I'm trying to deploy my first DocPad website to the [Gandi.net](http://www.gandi.net) hosting provider, with this service :
https://www.gandi.net/hebergement/simple?language=nodejs&grid=A

My code is here :
https://github.com/nylnook/nylnook-website
It's running fine locally on my computer.

Technically it seem to be a 'vhost', and I'm supposed to write a "server.js" file to deploy DocPad in production to the gandi server, after I used :

```
git push gandi master
```

('gandi' being my git remote repo at their server)
and also used a custom command (XXX instead of my login) :

```
ssh XXXXX@git.XXX.gpaas.net 'deploy default.git'
```

They have a guide for their Node.js instance :
[http://wiki.gandi.net/en/simple/instance/nodejs?s[]=node](http://wiki.gandi.net/en/simple/instance/nodejs?s%5B%5D=node)
and a guide for git usage on their servers :
http://wiki.gandi.net/en/simple/git

that suggest to use this code :
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/vhost/index.js

but I a newbie to node.js, learning with DocPad, so I can't figure how to do that !

Last link, the DocPad guide for deployment I followed so far :
http://docpad.org/docs/deploy

Thanks for you help !

Edit : another lead maybe :http://docpad.org/docs/api#using-with-express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself for documentation :
you need to modify 3 files

in server.js (thanks plflannery : https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/819) :

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn

var args = ['server'];
spawn('node_modules/.bin/docpad', args, {stdio:'inherit'}).on('close', function(err) {

if (err)
    console.log("docpad failed");
else
    console.log("docpad running");

});
```

in docpad.coffee, put :

```
port: 8080
```

in docpadConfig fonction, to change default port (9778) to
8080, as required by Gandi, explanations here :
https://github.com/bobobo1618/docpad-docum...

and in package.json put

```
"main": "server.js"
```

instead of

```
"main": "node_modules/docpad/bin/docpad-server"
```

So to launch docpad and install dependencies when deployment via Git.

Example of a working code :
https://github.com/nylnook/nylnook-website

Good luck in your projects !